# Vuetify, how to get row by double click event in v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to get row by event but it only give me event and undefeated, how to catch items in v-data-table

```
<v-data-table
          :headers="showHeaders"
          :page="page"
          :pageCount="numberOfPages"
          :options.sync="options"
          :loading="loading"
          :server-items-length="totalItems"
          :items="items"
          :items-per-page="15"
          class="mainTable"
          @dblclick:row="editItem(item, $event )"
          :footer-props="{
      showFirstLastPage: true,
      firstIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-left',
      lastIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-right',
      prevIcon: 'mdi-minus',
      nextIcon: 'mdi-plus'
    }"
```

---method---

```
    editItem (item, e) {
  console.log(item)
  this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item)
  this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
  this.dialog = true
},
```

what i've got

[only event but if i will transmits item it will be undefeated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvGh3.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to mention the parameters in the template :

```
@dblclick:row="editItem"
```

Note that the first parameter is the event and the second one is the row with following properties :

```
 {
  expand: (value: boolean) => void,
  headers: DataTableHeader[],
  isExpanded: boolean,
  isMobile: boolean,
  isSelected: boolean,
  item: any,
  select: (value: boolean) => void
}
```

the correct method :

```
editItem (event, {item}) {
  console.log(item)
  this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item)
  this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
  this.dialog = true
},
```

Comment: do you know exactly how that second parameter is being passed?  This sort of thing fails `@dblclick:row="editedItem($event.item)"`

Comment: Try `@dblclick:row="($event, {item})=>editedItem(item)"`

Comment: The obvious answer, always the one I don't think of...  It works.